# Laraver routing error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I have weird route error in Laravel. Stucked fixing it.
Here is my action (it is in simplified version).

```
public function ibf() {
    $existing_board_id = Input::get('existing_board_id');
    ...

    return Redirect::route('board.index')->with('success', 'Board is successfully imported.');
}
```

Form, here $board is new Model, not saved one, but with pre-defined values.

```
 {{ Form::model($board, ['route' => 'board.ibf',  'method' => 'POST', 'class' => 'form-horizontal']) }}
```

routes.php

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'board'), function() {
        Route::post('/ibf/', array(
        'as' => 'board.ibf',
        'uses' => 'BoardController@ibf'
    ));}
```

Error:

```
protected function methodNotAllowed(array $others)
{
    throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);
}
```

Everything looks simple, but I really dont understand the problem.

Comment: And what exactly you are doing when you getting this error? Do you send a form or just run url in browser?

Comment: I am just submitting form, I have many other forms, everything works, but this no. I dont understand where to look for an error.

Comment: what is the exact error?

Comment: Can you post your entire routes file. You are probably having your POST caught on a different route accidentally...

Comment: Here is screeshot http://i62.tinypic.com/1hloj.png

Comment: Can you post your `board.index` route as well

Comment: I have tried "/ibf" and "ibf/" doesnt helped. 
`Route::group(array('prefix' => 'board'), function() {
    Route::get('/', array(
        'as' => 'board.index',
        'uses' => 'BoardController@index'
    ));})`

Comment: The work flow is this: 1. Submitting file on first form. 2. Showing second form. 3. Saving second form. So when I am submitting second form getting this error. May be some cache problem? Or because submitting one form after another?

Comment: You need to edit your question - and post all the details. We need ALL your board routes, the controller and the forms. The problem could be any number of things.

Comment: my guess would be, you have duplicated named routes.

Comment: I have renamed this action several time but nothing

Comment: Add your entire route file to the question. Also add your entire error stack trace please.